# How to hide favourites bar in mac os using bash script?

Tags: macos, mac, bash

I'm trying to disable and enable the favourite bar in mac os "Yosemite" using bash script, I used the following command in terminal but it didn't work even after I restarted Safari, so am I doing something wrong?

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowFavoritesBar -bool false
```

Comment: even after relaunching the app? Otherwise, I'd guess there's nothing to prompt it to read the new setting

Comment: I restarted the app :(

Comment: defaults read says it doesn't exist. I tested defaults read com.apple.Safari ShowStatusBar for comparison, which does exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a -v2 for Yosemite.  See below:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowFavoritesBar-v2 -bool false
```

Restart Safari.